# Minimize waste for wood router machine

Tags: optimization

I am not sure if this is the right place to ask this question but of all StackExchange communities, this looks to be the closest one.

We have to cut an equal number of circles of 5 different diameters - D1, ..., D5 from wooden tiles of LxL cm. The working space of our router machine has the size WxH cm, W < L < H.

How to cut (with straight lines) the tiles so that they fit into the working space of the router machine and how to place the circles on those cut parts so that the waste is minimized?

The sizes

- L = 150
- W = 120
- H = 250
- D1 = 40/42 (the second number includes padding for the knife)
- D2 = 45/47
- D3 = 50/52
- D4 = 55/57
- D5 = 60/62

The reason I asked the question here is that I thought that there might be some known optimization problem and one could point it to me. May be a good brute force suggestion?

Comment: You want to first make straight-line cuts of the tiles into smaller pieces, so that each piece fits in the working space, and then cut out circles from those pieces?  Are you told how many circles of each type you want to produce?  I don't understand what "padding for the knife" means or what effect that has on what solutions are considered valid -- can it be safely ignored?

Comment: The answer to the first question is yes. We need to cut 40 pieces of each type. 

The padding part means, that the circles cannot "touch" each other, since the knife ( drill ) has a finite size. That is why I  increased the diameters by 2 cm, so that the minimal distance between 2 cuts is at least 2 cm.

Comment: Can I ignore the knife/drill size and just treat it as drawing circles of diameter 42, and assume the cuts are perfectly precise and infinitely thin?

Comment: Yes. you can do that.